# Threats from ex-employer

Tags: united-kingdom

I was dismissed from my company for so-called poor performance, however I received no warning nor anything in writing and have received nothing since.

I recently started working for a rival company and now I am receiving telephone threats from my ex-employer with reference he will tell me who I can deal with and if I don't agree he will take legal action to recoup the salary he has paid me over the previous 6 months.

Comment: Contact a lawyer. Depending on your contract you signed with your previous employer he might be in his right to do what he is doing.

Comment: Did you sign a non-compete clause?

Comment: Also, in some jurisdictions, being dismissed requires written from - so maybe he also owes you some more money?

Comment: I signed no Non-compete clause

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "with reference he will tell me who i can deal with", do you mean that he is threatening to withhold the reference?  It's not entirely clear what you mean, please explain.  Also if you earned a salary while working for him then he can't reclaim *anything* if it  was paid correctly.  I would strongly recommend speaking to either ACAS or a lawyer, you can usually get an initial consultation for free.

Comment: To make a better question: your dismissal, did you get paper work from that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is your ex employer asking you to agree to?

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: Not an answer as IANAL but non compete clause are pretty hard to enforce in the UK, even more so if they sack you, as this often invalidates them anyway.

Comment: @Jeroen err no you cant recover 6 months wages like that and not following procedures to dismiss is automatically unfair and you'd win  a tribuneral,

Answer (score 7):

> I was dismissed from my company for so-called poor performance, however I received no warning nor anything in writing and have received nothing since.

If you've really had no warning and nothing in writing about your *dismissal*, then I'd contact a lawyer - you may still be legally employed at your former work, and this may be the basis of his complaints (in this case it may be nothing to do with a non-compete clause.)

If so then it's a messy situation, and professional legal advice is really the best way forward. (The same applies if you have paperwork around your dismissal, but may have signed a non-compete clause or similar.)

If you had paperwork and documentation to prove your dismissal, and you're sure you didn't sign a non-compete clause then you have two realistic options:

- Try to mend relationships (at least to an extent) with your former boss; talk to him, try to understand why exactly he thinks he can take you to court, what exactly he thinks you've done wrong and learn from it. Of course, things may be entirely beyond that now, in which case;
- Just ignore him, don't answer any calls, block his number if you can, and try to move on. Just remember that you have no way of getting a positive reference from this company / individual in the future - which may or may not be a problem, depending on your circumstance.

Comment: One way to mend the relationship:  "Old boss this will help you guys to have such a poor performer working on the rival's product"!